# What is the difference between the various xsl files included with CheckStyle?

Tags: java, xslt, static-analysis, checkstyle

The CheckStyle distribution contains several example XSL files for formatting reports.  With CheckStyle 5.0, they are:

```
checkstyle-author.xsl
checkstyle-csv.xsl
checkstyle-frames-errors.xsl
checkstyle-frames.xsl
checkstyle-noframes-sorted.xsl
checkstyle-noframes.xsl
checkstyle-simple.xsl
checkstyle-text.xsl
```

Some of the names are more obvious than others.  I'm trying to figure out the exact features in each so that I can pick one for an automated build.

Answer (score 1):

These are style sheets that have been contributed to the Checkstyle project overtime. The best approach is to just try each one and see what works best for you (sorry, there is not other way).

Personally, there days I use the reports generated by Maven and/or Hudson (Jenkins?).